Azure Data Factory REST connector not accepting Accept header
I am using Azure Data Factory to run a pipeline that invokes REST API. For this I am using ADF REST connector. As per documentation, Accept header only takes value as application/json. But the problem is the API that I am invoking is maintaining versions in the Accept header like application/***v2+json so unable to pass the same.
Can someone let me know if it's possible or any workaround?

REST connector ignores any "Accept" header specified in
additionalHeaders. As REST connector only support response in JSON, it
will auto generate a header of Accept: application/json

Update: I am able to invoke API using HTTP connector by passing Accept header as required in this case. But would want if this is possible with REST connector.

add the configuration screenshot of rest connector you have.

Another option is to set-up a proxy-server somewhere that rewrites the request headers. I'll admit I'm disappointed with the rigid inflexibility of ADF's current "REST" tooling, but given your service's flagrant misuse of the Accept header for API versioning is just so out-of-leftfield that all I can do is give you my sympathy (and/or pity).

@Dai The thing is that the API that we are calling is an external one that is not in our control :(

I imagine you can fix this with an indirection via Azure Functions

@JayashankarGS Sorry but what configuration screenshot is required? As I mentioned above, I want to pass Accept header as 'application/{vnd}v2+json' but REST is not allowing as it accepts only 'application/json'

@Dai you mean instead of using ADF REST connector, I invoke service using Azure functions?

@Anand Something like that, yes - but I'm just making broad and general suggestions - I've only ever toyed with ADF (and I found it very lacking - I find I can often do my own data-integrations and ETL using LinqPad or SSIS and avoid ADF's running costs too).

@Dai Thanks!!. I have updated my post as well.. It works with HTTP connector so I guess I can use HTTP instead of REST.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
